# What are good ways to convert EPS to PDF?

Tags: pdf, conversion, eps

I'd like to try to use pdfLaTeX to generate PDFs but my images are all in EPS.  I would also like for the images to remain scalable.

I have tried using ImageMagik's `convert`:

```bsh
convert file.eps file.pdf
```

but the result does not look good and the image becomes grainy after a few zooms.

I try `epstopdf file.eps`, but get the following error message:

```
Error: /undefined in II*
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1878   1   3   %oparray_pop   1877   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   1861   1   3   %oparray_pop   1755   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1160/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:89/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2
GPL Ghostscript 8.71: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

which doesn't really tell me anything.

Anyone know any other ways to convert EPS to PDF?  (I have about 200 images, so command-line is better)

Comment: Where do your EPS images come from that they don't work with epstopdf?

Comment: illustrator CS3..  actually most seemed to work ok in the end, but one cover page got so cropped with epstopdf that I had to resave it as pdf from illustrator directly.  No idea why..

Comment: I too have received errors like that when using `epstopdf`. I've found that in those cases running `eps2eps` before seems to work.

Comment: See also [How to convert PDF to EPS?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20883/how-to-convert-pdf-to-eps). Some tools are able to convert both ways (Ghostscript, InkScape).

Comment: A simple command is: `epspdf file.eps` I wonder how people here did not find this!

Comment: `epspdf` is exactly the same as `epstopdf` which is discussed in OP's question.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[`epstopdf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf), of course, which is what the [`epstopdf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf-pkg) package relies on. (If you used the package there would be no need to convert.)

Or is that what you meant by `eps2pdf`? I've never noticed any problems with it.

I suppose you could also try [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/); I think it does have some batch functions, perhaps even command-line options for conversion, even though it is principally a GUI app.

EDIT: Judging by [the inkscape manual](http://inkscape.modevia.com/inkscape-man.html), you could just do:

```bsh
inkscape --export-pdf=output.pdf input.eps
```

EDIT2: Actually, you might need to use SVG input for inkscape export on the command-line; I'll look into this a bit more. You could do it through the GUI, though.

Comment: sorry... yeah, mistake... I meant epstopdf

Comment: The `epstopdf` package relies on `\write18` being enabled. It's a nice feature, but a bad idea. Just run `epstopdf` yourself.

Comment: @TH: You could just pass the appropriate command-line flag to pdflatex, which you can find in the `epstopdf` manual...

Comment: +1 for `inkscape` which works really nice for me. No issues with font changes etc. so far.

Comment: Thanks, very useful. I managed this on WSL2 inkscape install on a folder with many eps using this magic `for i in *.eps; do  echo $i; inkscape --export-pdf=${i%.eps}.pdf $i; done`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19654/how-do-i-change-the-extension-of-multiple-files

Answer (score 7):

You can use `ps2pdf` with options to suppress resampling and lossily compressing images `-dAutoFilterColorImages=false` and `-dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode`. (On windows, replace the `=` by `#`).

`ps2pdf` may not keep the same bounding box, unlike `epstopdf`, but you can fix that either by copying the logic from `epstopdf` (eg, edit `epstopdf.pl` to add those options to the ghostscript command line) or you can redo the clipping by using `pdfcrop`.

Comment: With those flags, will `ps2pdf` also avoid *decoding* images using the `DCTEncode` filter, such as would be produced by losslessly converting a JPEG file to EPS with http://pts.szit.bme.hu/sam2p/?

Comment: @SamB Adobe Distiller (since version 6) has a parameter `PassThroughJPEGImages`. Unfortunately, `ghostscript` (the engine underlying `ps2pdf`) does not support this distiller parameter. See item 3.8 in [the ghostscript projects page](http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Projects.htm) (has been a project since 2000, don't hold your breath). Because of this, sam2p is much less useful than it seems at first, and using eps as an intermediate format on the way to pdf is not attractive.... See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2092/which-figure-type-to-use-pdf-or-eps/2093#2093)

Answer (score 4):

I always use the following batch file

```
echo off
latex %1
del %1.log
del %1.aux
dvips %1 -E -o %1-crop.eps
del %1.dvi
epstool --copy --bbox %1-crop.eps %1.eps
del %1-crop.eps
epstopdf --hires %1.eps
```

in my job to compile an example:

```
% gridoff.tex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](3,3)
\pscircle(1.5,1.5){1}
\rput[tr](3,3){3}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

It runs without problem. The important parts that you need are

```
epstool --copy --bbox input.eps output.eps
epstopdf --hires output.eps
```

The first invokes GhostScript to append high resolution bounding box. The last converts EPS to PDF with high resolution bounding box.

Comment: `epstool` is also relevant in another matter. Illustrator may embed a preview image into the EPS, which `epstopdf` then does not like. To remove it use `epstool -p input.eps output.eps`

Comment: While I told you to use `<pre>` tags for non-TeX code, Caramdir's suggestion to use language specifications is actually better. See [Is there some trick to writing code snippets?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-some-trick-to-writing-code-snippets/1510#1510) on meta now. (No reason to change existing post; just for future reference, because it is easier and leads to better results)

Comment: @xport: Simply use `lang-none` then.

Comment: @xport: You forgot the indention. Use a normal code block but add the language specification before. See my edit.