# How to avoid large margins around Matlab plot in PDF

Tags: graphics, pdf, crop, matlab

I am preparing image files to be included in a latex document. The image file is generated by printing a Matlab plot.

If I print the plot in eps format, the content of the eps file is fully occupied with the plot;

if I print the plot in pdf format, then there are big margins above and below the plot in the pdf file;

if I use ps2pdf to convert the eps file into a pdf file, the big margins will be added above the plot.

I would like to use pdflatex, so I prefer pdf format of image files. I was wondering how I can save the plot in pdf format without the big margin above and below the plot?

Comment: Maybe your question is answered [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2872/1235). (Possible duplicate?)

Comment: @Hendrik That question is related but not a duplicate IMO.

Comment: Here's a blog entry describing a way to reduce the whitespace that Matlab puts around plots: http://nibot-lab.livejournal.com/73290.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is partially off-topic, since LaTeX doesn't have anything to do with how the PDF is generated. Nonetheless, it's relevant enough for my tastes.

In Matlab, you can create a cropped PDF by setting the papersize to the same size as the graphic; see [this small `figuresize.m` function](https://github.com/wspr/matlabpkg/blob/master/figuresize.m) to do this automatically.

Usually if you're generating graphics from Matlab, though, I'd recommend using [matlabfrag](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21286-matlabfrag) so that your figure labels are typeset by LaTeX. You can use psfrag-based graphics in pdfLaTeX by using the `pstool` package.

Finally, if you just want to crop a graphic, TeX Live and MiKTeX both come with a command line tool `pdfcrop` to perform this on an arbitrary PDF.

Comment: And of course there is `matlab2tikz` (http://win.ua.ac.be/~nschloe/content/matlab2tikz), for all your Matlab related graphics in `tikz`.

Comment: @Pieter Yes, I forgot to mention, because I haven't started using it yet; so far I'm still at the stage of exporting my data from Matlab manually when I want to use pgfplots, which technique works well so far.

Comment: Just for posterity: `matlab2tikz` has moved to https://github.com/nschloe/matlab2tikz.

Comment: `matlab2tikz` have been further moved to https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz

Answer (score 19):

**pdfcrop** should help remove the margins. I use it like so:

```
pdfcrop -margins 10 fig.pdf fig.pdf
```

Answer (score 8):

how about trimming the image by using the options of the `\includegraphics` command?

here is an example `\includegraphics[trim = 35mm 95mm 40mm 100mm, clip, 
width=0.475\textwidth]`

Comment: IS there a way of obtaining the trim numbers apart from trial and error?

Answer (score 8):

[Export_fig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-exportfig) makes all the work automatically, including margins and pdf creation.
The original Matlab save result is: [image: Original Matlab print command]
export_fig results (picture size is the same) is: [image]

Note: this command is the improvement of [savefig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10889-savefig) command.

**Update**: Starting version 2020a, the new Matlab command `exportgraphics` seems to do the job.

Comment: This worked well for me. I'm using Windows and I had to install ghostscript in order to be able to produce .pdf files with export_fig. My steps were: 1) Install ghostscript; 2) Download the export_fig .zip file, unzip, add the resulting folder to my matlab path; 3) Create a MATLAB figure and use the MATLAB command `export_fig('MyFigure.pdf')` to save the figure as a .pdf file.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way of removing whitespace around a Matlab figure is

```
subplot('position',[0 0 1 1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

`set(gca, 'LooseInset', get(gca,'TightInset'))`

Deletes the margins in the figure previous to the exporting.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. (Tested with Matlab 2014b.)

Comment: It worked for me, when `PaperSize` and related properties were set correctly. Strangely, I only needed to add this option on Ubuntu. On Mac OS even without this line the code produces the expected result. Seems like there is a difference in rendering mechanism depending on the platform. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

if you are happy with the eps images and want similar pdf images (in terms of margins), you should use epstopdf (and not ps2pdf).This is mentionned in Hendrik's link.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [eps2pdf](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5782-eps2pdf) matlab script.

```
print -depsc testeps;
eps2pdf testeps.eps;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a MATLAB package that automatically generates figures with a tighter crop (and offers other nice things): [savefig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10889-savefig)

Answer (score 2):

I really like to take a lot of control when exporting my figures by pre-defining the margins and paper-size to be my desired figure size.  This makes fonts size correctly, and lets you choose the margins you want.

First I define my figure width and height (these are in metric, but you can use US units also).

```
FigW=13.49414;
FigH=21.08462*.3;
```

Next, I set my figure properties.  First I define the text interpreter to be latex, and then I set the paper size.  You can define margins in the paper position parameter, but i prefer to do that later.  if you want to use inches, that's fine here.  Finally the 'Position' option just makes the figure on screen look identical to what will be printed to PDF.  The first two parameters in 'Position' are the screen position and the second are the width and height of the figure.

```
Figure1=figure(1);clf;
    set(Figure1,'defaulttextinterpreter','latex',...
                'PaperUnits','centimeters','PaperSize',[FigW FigH],...
                'PaperPosition',[0,0,FigW,FigH],'Units','centimeters',...
                'Position',[1,10,FigW,FigH]);
```

I then use the [subaxis package from the mathworks file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3696-subaxis-subplot) to take control of my margins, padding and spacing of all my subplots.  For one plot this might look like:

```
subaxis(1,1,1,'Margin',.1);
```

Finally, I export to PDF using the print command in matlab:

```
print('-dpdf','-r500','filename.pdf')
```

Answer (score 1):

And, of course, if you're a complete graphic-fewl you can export your matlab data to asymptote for making really beautiful plots that rise to the level of the rest of your beautiful latex-created document. Asymptote can create pdf output directly, which looks really great in pdflatex docs. I haven't noticed that there's any extra spacing either.

Comment: Personally I prefer matplotlib (a python library), it allows the same quality graphics with matlab syntax (a + for new learners) and can output eps or pdf as well.And since it sits in numpy, it can do all your data analysis as well :D

Answer (score 1):

I voted question up even though I also agree that is a bit off topic. I use MATLAB in particular to create nice animation but when it comes to pictures I just export pictures into PostScript and then use [GraphcisMagic](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/)
to crop, resize or do whatever you like. GraphcisMagic can also convert from ps/eps format into pdf but people already mentioned half dozen tools that can accomplish the same.