# How can I plot bigger amounts of data?

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot, csv

I am currently playing around with hailstone sequences (collatz numbers).

I would like to create a plot like this (from [Wikipedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:CollatzStatistic100million.png)):

[image]

But I don't know how this kind of plot is called (it's neither a line plot, nor a scatter plot or a bar chart or a histogram, although it looks similar).

I would like to plot how many steps you need from a number `n` to get to `1`. The x-axis should be numbers (from 1 to M, with M as high as possible) and the y-axis should be the number of steps.

As I didn't know how the kind of plot above is called (and I was not able to find a name) I used a scatterplot:

[image]

Sadly, this seems to consume a lot of memory. Plotting 4100 (n, steps from n to 1) pairs worked, but when I increased it to 4150 pairs, I got:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000].
\endvarwidth ...\vbox \bgroup \unvcopy \@tempboxa 
                                                  \@tempdima -\maxdimen \let...
l.28 \end{document}
```

I think the following could eventually solve my problem:

- switch to gnuplot (I have no idea how to read a CSV-file with gnuplot and I only used gnuplot+LaTeX once. Does anybody have a minimal working example with instructions how to compile it?)
- switch diagram type to the diagram above (How is it called?)
- don't actually write the numbers n in csv file, but get it from the line number (How can I get the line number from a CSV file in my code below for x?)
- switch to [another type of plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43297/5645) like here (I guess this will be more complicated and it seems as if I had to use gnuplot / R. Does anybody know how to apply this to my problem?)

All code I've written is [on GitHub](https://github.com/MartinThoma/algorithms/tree/master/collatz/visualizations). This is the LaTeX code I've written so far:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} %layout

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            enlarge y limits=true,
            %xmin=0, xmax=2150,
            %ymin=0, ymax=600,
            width=15cm, height=8cm,     % size of the image
            grid = major,
            grid style={dashed, gray!30},
            ylabel=steps,
            xlabel=$n$,
            legend style={at={(0.1,-0.1)}, anchor=north}
         ]
          \addplot[scatter,only marks] table [x=n, y=steps, col sep=comma] {../steps.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to plot at least 100,000 elements (rather 10,000,000 if possible). How can I do it?

Comment: Is the first one like a comb plot (see the `pgfplots` manual)?

Comment: Yes, xcomb (http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html ) looks like what I would like to get :-) I'll try it in two hours (currently I'm in a lecture). Do you know how to get rid of the dots at the end?

Comment: Not sure if this will help much, but you can increase the capacity of TeX's memory. See for example [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27529/increase-tex-capacity-as-non-root).

Comment: Torbjørn T.: Thanks, it worked as expected (I couldn't resist to try it and leaved the lecture). 
@MarcvanDongen: This will not help, as I have 4GB in total and I already gave TeX 3GB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### pgfplots, comb plot

Thanks to Torbjørn T., who has suggested to look at `comb plots`. This allowed me to plot 7150 (but not 7200) data points:

[image]

## gnuplot

### crosses

[image]

You have to create a file that tells gnuplot what to do. I've called it `plot.gnuplot`:

```
set terminal latex
set output "plot-tmp.tex"
set datafile separator "," 
set title "Collatz Number of steps"
plot '../steps.csv' every::1
```

Then you have to run gnuplot: `gnuplot plot.gnuplot`
This will produce a "plot-tmp.tex" that can be included into your LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\input plot-tmp
\end{document}
```

This allows me to plot 22300 data points (but not 22350).

### comb plot

To get a comb plot, you have to add "with impulses to the plot command. So your plot.gnuplot file should look like this:

```
set terminal latex
set output "plot-tmp.tex"
set datafile separator "," 
set title "Collatz Number of steps"
plot '../steps.csv' every::1 with impulses
```

which produces:

[image]

## R

You can (should?) plot large data to PDF-files with R. R could handle the 120 MB file with 10,000,000 data points.

To do so, you have to install R and ggplot2 (`sudo apt-get install r-cran-ggplot2`).

Now you can start R from command line with `sudo R` (it has to be a capital letter) to install hexbin: `install.packages("hexbin", dependencies=TRUE);` ([source](http://dingo.ucsf.edu/twiki/bin/view/Cores/BioinformaticsCore/InstallingPackagesInR))

Now create a file called `analyze.R` and copy this:

```
library(ggplot2)

mydata = read.csv("/home/moose/Downloads/algorithms/collatz/steps.csv")

# Prepare data
p<-ggplot(mydata, aes ( x=n,y=steps ))

# Plus means you add those options to the plot
p + geom_hex( bins=30 ) + opts(panel.background = theme_rect(fill='white', colour='white'))
```

Execute it: `R -f analyze.R`

And you get:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The formulation of the question looks a bit confusing. 
First it talks about the graph from `Wikipedia` link, which is an ordinary bar chart that represents a histogram:
for every integer `x` (the number of steps to reach `1` from some number from `1..100000000`) there is an integer `y` (the amount of numbers from that interval,
that have the same number of steps `x`). Note, that the `x` range is not so big,
just less than `600` individual points collect the statistics obtained from `100mln` numbers.
Next question is more simple and more difficult at the same time:
to plot the number of steps for every number tested in a range.
It is simpler, because there is no need to accumulate the amount 
of numbers with the same `x` steps, while the difficulty is...
To plot such a graph with, say, a "humble number" of `100000` points,
every point has to be plotted (otherwise it would be just some kind of useless random mess).
Assuming that every bar is just one point wide, to print if at `1200dpi`, 
the total width of the `x`-axis would be roughly **two meters wide**.

So, this `Asymptote` code (without any extra programs) 
is used to plot the same kind of the graph as that of `Wikipedia` link, 
a statistics obtained from `nMax=100000000` (100mln)
numbers. It took about 20 min to run in the background on a not-very-advanced laptop.
The histogram data are accumulated in the integer array `stepCount` and printed to `stdout`. The output also includes:

- `n=100000000` - max number in a range tested,
- `highest=2185143829170100` - max number reached during the whole test,
- `maxStep=949` max number of steps to reach `1`,
- `maxStepArg=63728127` the number, that needs `maxStep` steps to reach `1`.

So, starting from `63728127` it should take `949` steps to get `1`.

`collatz.asy:`

```
import graph;
int nMax=100000000;
int highest=1;
int maxStepArg=1;
int[] arStep=array(nMax,0); 

int stepMaxLimit=1000;
int[] stepCount=array(stepMaxLimit,0); 

int steps(int nn){
  int n=nn;
  int m=0;
  int nextn;
  while(n>1){
    if((n%2)==0){
      nextn=floor(n/2);
      ++m;
    }else{
      assert(n<floor((intMax-1)/3),"too big n="+string(n));
      nextn=3n+1;
      highest=max(highest,nextn);
      ++m;
    }
    if(nextn<arStep.length && arStep[nextn-1]>0){
      m+=arStep[nextn-1];
      n=1;
      return m;
    }else{
      n=nextn;
    }
  }
  return m;
}

int maxStep=1;
int j;
for(int i=1;i<=nMax;++i){
  j=steps(i);
  ++stepCount[j];
  if(j>maxStep){
    maxStep=j;
    maxStepArg=i;
  }
  arStep[i-1]=j;
}

write("n="+string(nMax)
+", highest="+string(highest)
+", maxStep = "+string(maxStep)
+", maxStepArg = "+string(maxStepArg)
);

size(256,256,IgnoreAspect);
int nj;
real t;

pen barPen=rgb(0,0,0.5608)+opacity(0.6)+0.8pt;
guide g=(0,0);
for(int i=1;i<=maxStep;++i){
  g=g--(i,stepCount[i])--(i+1,stepCount[i])--(i+1,0);
}
g=g--cycle;

fill(g,barPen);
xaxis(0,maxStep,RightTicks());
yaxis(0,max(stepCount),LeftTicks(beginlabel=false));

write(stepCount[0:maxStep+4]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I make the hailstone graph via Asymptote for this 10-year-old question. It's exciting that [the Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) is still open.

To draw, I use a `struct` named `Collatz` with 3 attributes: `chain` for the chain, `len` and `max_value` for its length (stopping time) and maximum value. In case one wants the bar graph, just replace `dot((i,d),2pt+red);` by
`draw((i,d)--(i,0),blue);`

It takes a few second with `n=10000` to compile online. I have not yet tested to run offline.

[image]

[image]

```
// Collatz: the hailstone graph
// Run on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/ 
    
struct Collatz {
    int[] chain;      // the Collatz chain
    int len;          // the length of the Collatz chain
    int max_value;    // the maximum of the Collatz chain
}

Collatz collatz_calculate(int n) {
    Collatz c;   
    c.chain.push(n);  // Initialise the chain with the first node n
    c.len = 1;        // Initialise the length chain as 1
    c.max_value = n;  // Initialise the maximum value as n
  
    while (n > 1) {
        n = (n % 2 == 0) ? (n # 2) : (3 * n + 1);
        c.chain.push(n);
        ++ c.len;
        c.max_value = max(n, c.max_value);
    }
    return c;
}

import graph;
size(12cm,8cm,IgnoreAspect);
int n = 10000;
for (int i=2; i < n; ++i) { 
    int d = collatz_calculate(i).len;
    //draw((i,d)--(i,0),blue);    // the bar graph
    dot((i,d),2pt+red);           // the hailstone graph
}

xaxis("$n$",BottomTop,LeftTicks);
yaxis("stopping time",LeftRight,RightTicks);
label("\bfseries Collatz conjecture: hailstone graph",point(N),2N);
shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```