# Randomly choose to plot some number of points from a CSV file for pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-3dplot

I have the following code (taken as an example from: [Scatterplot with data from CSV file and trendline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204593/scatterplot-with-data-from-csv-file-and-trendline)) which plots a 3d scatterplot from a csv file.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{table.dat}
 x y
 0 1
100 3
150 2
200 5
300 6
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}[
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        enlarge y limits=true,
        width=15cm, height=8cm,     % size of the image
        grid = major,
        grid style={dashed, gray!30},
         ylabel=steps,
         xlabel=$n$,
         legend style={at={(0.1,-0.1)}, anchor=north}
      ]        
     \addplot[only marks] table  {table.dat};

 \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

Is there any way I can have only a few points plotted from the csv file?

Comment: Welcome! Yes, there sure is. However, users will be much more eager to help you if you (a) provide them with a complete document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and (b) add a small sample data file that we can play with.

Comment: If you do not want to provide us with a working example, let mention that you are most likely looking for a filter, which can for instance select points with an appropriate `\corrdindex`. If you want to have this spelled out, please go the extra mile and provide us with something that makes it us easier to write an answer.

Comment: I apologize for the delay. I have updated the code with a working simple example of a scatter plot. However, I will lookup \corrdindex see if I can use that command. Thank you so much!

Comment: \corrdindex is the perfect answer, worked like a charm! Thank you @Schrödinger'scat for the answer!

Comment: You're welcome. (I realized that I mistyped `\coordindex` but I guess you figured that out.) Please let me know if your problem solved, or there is anything to do.

Comment: Yes my issue is solved.