# Problems with including a tikz tex file generated by Octave (MatLab clone)

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, matlab, octave

I have plotted a figure in Octave and printed it as a TikZ figure (see the [*device* option](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Printing-Plots.html)) to a tex file called `comparison_tikz.tex`, and I have imported it into my document with the line

```
\input{comparison_tikz.tex}
```

I have also included the tikz package in the preamble of my document. However, when I try to compile the document, I get the following errors:

```
line 17   Use of \tikz@parse@cs@xy polar doesn't match its definition ...gb]{0,0,0}{{25}}}{}{\pgfusepath{discard}}}
line 17   Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup ...gb]{0,0,0}{{25}}}{}{\pgfusepath{discard}}}
line 0    Missing control sequence inserted
```

I tried to google it but I couldn't find anything about the error. I see that it complains about something with polar coordinates, but the plot I've made doesn't use polar coordinates.

When I double click on any of the error messages, it takes me to line 17 in the generated file (which looks almost exactly like other lines in the file). Anyway, here is the beginning of the file:

```
% Title: glps_renderer figure
% Creator: GL2PS 1.3.6, (C) 1999-2011 C. Geuzaine
% For: Octave
% CreationDate: Wed Jun 13 08:48:06 2012
\begin{pgfpicture}
{
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{246.399994pt}{73.195633pt}}
\pgfnode{rectangle}{north}{\fontsize{10}{0}\selectfont\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{{10}}}{}{\pgfusepath{discard}}}
{
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{333.199982pt}{73.195633pt}}
\pgfnode{rectangle}{north}{\fontsize{10}{0}\selectfont\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{{15}}}{}{\pgfusepath{discard}}}
{
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{419.999969pt}{73.195633pt}}
\pgfnode{rectangle}{north}{\fontsize{10}{0}\selectfont\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{{20}}}{}{\pgfusepath{discard}}}
{
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{506.799957pt}{73.195633pt}}
\pgfnode{rectangle}{north}{\fontsize{10}{0}\selectfont\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{{25}}}{}{\pgfusepath{discard}}} % This is the line causing the error
{
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{67.799995pt}{78.200020pt}}
\pgfnode{rectangle}{east}{\fontsize{10}{0}\selectfont\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{{0}}}{}{\pgfusepath{discard}}}
{
```

If I print the plot as a tex figure instead and try to include that it also gives me an error when I try to compile the document; the generated tex file then looks like

```
% Title: glps_renderer figure
% Creator: GL2PS 1.3.6, (C) 1999-2011 C. Geuzaine
% For: Octave
% CreationDate: Wed Jun 13 08:48:05 2012
\setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\includegraphics{}
\end{picture}% This is the line causing the error
\begin{picture}(576,412)(0,0)
\fontsize{10}{0}
\selectfont\put(246.4,33.1956){\makebox(0,0)[t]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{{10}}}}
\fontsize{10}{0}
\selectfont\put(333.2,33.1956){\makebox(0,0)[t]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{{15}}}}
\fontsize{10}{0}
\selectfont\put(420,33.1956){\makebox(0,0)[t]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{{20}}}}
\fontsize{10}{0}
\selectfont\put(506.8,33.1956){\makebox(0,0)[t]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{{25}}}}
\fontsize{10}{0}
\selectfont\put(67.8,38.2){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{{0}}}}
\fontsize{10}{0}
\selectfont\put(67.8,95.25){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{{0.005}}}}
\fontsize{10}{0}
\selectfont\put(72.8,33.1956){\makebox(0,0)[t]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{{0}}}}
\fontsize{10}{0}
\selectfont\put(159.6,33.1956){\makebox(0,0)[t]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{{5}}}}
\fontsize{10}{0}
\selectfont\put(67.8,152.3){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{{0.01}}}}
\fontsize{10}{0}
\selectfont\put(67.8,209.35){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{{0.015}}}}
\fontsize{10}{0}
\selectfont\put(67.8,266.4){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{{0.02}}}}
\fontsize{10}{0}
\selectfont\put(67.8,323.45){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{{0.025}}}}
\fontsize{10}{0}
\selectfont\put(67.8,380.5){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{{0.03}}}}
\end{picture}
```

The error message reads

```
line 0    File `' not found.
```

and when I double click on the message it takes me to line 8 in the generated file.

What is it about these files that LaTeX doesn't like? I think they should work properly since it is Octave that has generated them. Do I need to set up my document in some certain way in order to be able to use the files?

**Edit 1 (Solved):** Here is a minimal (not) working example for the tex figure:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\begin{document}

\input{comparison.tex}

\end{document}
```

where `comparison.tex` is the latter of the two generated tex files included above. This gives me the compilation error

```
line 11   Undefined control sequence ...box(0,0)[t]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{{10}}}}
line 13   Undefined control sequence ...box(0,0)[t]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,0}{{15}}}}
```

and so on for the lines 11, 13, 15, ... 35 in comparison.tex. It highlights the `\put` and the `\makebox` macros in the code.

**Edit 2:** And here is a minimal (not) working example for the TikZ figure:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx,color}
\begin{document}

\input{comparison_tikz.tex}

\end{document}
```

where `comparison_tikz.tex` is the former of the two generated tex files included above. This gives me the compilation error

```
line 17   Use of \tikz@parse@cs@xy polar doesn't match its definition ...gb]{0,0,0}{{25}}}{}{\pgfusepath{discard}}}
line 17   Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup ...gb]{0,0,0}{{25}}}{}{\pgfusepath{discard}}}
line 0    Missing control sequence inserted
line 0    \begin{pgfpicture} on input line 5 ended by \end{document}.
```

Comment: Could you provide us with a 'complete' minimal (not) working example? This is: plot a line with octave and show us all the files you obtain and how do you include them in a complete .tex document (from `\documentclass{}` to `\end{document}` with all necessary `\usepackage`.)

Comment: @Ignasi: Fixed. I don't really know which packages the generated code expects so I didn't include any. Heck — it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Which TikZ/PGF version are you using?

Comment: @Martin: How can I find that out? All I know is that I'm using TeXstudio 2.3 which I installed a few weeks ago. I don't even remember if I've installed MikTeX manually, but I see that MikTeX 2.9 is installed on the computer.

Comment: Package versions are independent from the MiKTeX version. The simplest way is to look in the log file, especially if you use `\listfiles`. The MiKTeX package manager will also tell it and can be used to update the package if it is too old.

Comment: @Martin: `Package: pgf 2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)`, `Package: tikz 2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)`

Comment: Ok, that's the most recent version.

Comment: I have the same problem with generated PGF picture. I get the same error messages about some polar stuff. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to use [this octave script](http://2pif.info/tutorial/pgfprint-en.html) which generates TeX code using the `pgfplots` package. It's limited, but it can do basic curve plotting, but needs some modification if you want it to support the more advanced features of `pgfplots`.

Comment: If you are interested in this kind of conversion, you may want to take a look at the `matlab2tikz` project. Perhaps it works for octave as well - and it allows quite sophisticated results.

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely take a look at that if I am going to plot more figures for TeX/LaTeX documents!

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 5):

Your MWE uses commands from the `graphicx` and `color` packages but does not load them so produces errors about undefined commands. So it needs to be

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\begin{document}

\input{comparison.tex} % Uses commands from the graphicx and color packages

\end{document}
```

Then line 7 of the included file is

```
 \includegraphics{}
```

which is nonsense, including a graphic without specifying a file name, so you get an error about a missing file.

If you change that to

```
%\includegraphics{}
```

It runs without error.

Comment: Thanks! It's strange though that Octave would generate tex code that won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

I found a partial solution to the TikZ issue. The Octave documentation says that FLTK produces PGF code. That means all plots created while using FLTK for the graphics will be saved as a PGF picture. On the other hand `gnuplot` will create TikZ pictures. These do compile if you do the following:

1. Find `gnuplot-lua-tikz.sty`. The path should be something like `C:\octave\gnuplot\share\texmf\tex\latex`.
2. Add the directory called `texmf` to the list of registered root directories via MiKTeX Options.
3. Add `\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}` to the preamble of your document.
4. In Octave, execute `graphics_toolkit('gnuplot')` before you do any plotting. Then save your plots using the `-dtikz` option as before, and `\input` the created file.

The PGF code generated by FLTK remains an unresolved issue.

Comment: If I replace the `pgfpicture` environment with `tikzpicture` environment and don't touch the content in the question it compiles properly. But for such operations I would recommend exporting the data and using `pgfplots` as is evident from the plot that the code is far from optimized.

Comment: Funny you should mention that you found a partial solution the same day I found [this page](http://2pif.info/tutorial/pgfprint-en.html). It is an octave script that generates TeX code using the `pgfplot` package, and it works if all you want is to do basic curve plotting, and the results look quite okay. It needs some modification though if you want to use some of the more advanced features of `pgfplot`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, and the solution is much simpler than
what I first thought. Take a look at the help page from Octave's print
function:

The text that is written to
               the LaTeX file contains the strings *exactly* as they
               were specified in the plot.  If any special characters of
               the TeX mode interpreter were used, the file must be
               edited before LaTeX processing.  **Specifically, the
               special characters must be enclosed with dollar signs
               ('$ ... $'),** and other characters that are recognized by
               LaTeX may also need editing (e.g., braces).

Indeed, wrapping my math expressions in Octave plot with dollars instantly solved the compilation problem.