# .eps file generated by matlab not centered correctly

Tags: graphics, pdf, eps, matlab

Everything is all right before I updated all my MiKTeX package to latest version. But after that, I find that all `.eps` file generated by Matlab cannot be shown correctly.

For example. I use Matlab to plot sin(n)

```
n = 1:0.1:50;
plot(n, sin(n));
```

And I got the figure like this.

[image: matlab figure]

I use Matlab 2013a(tested in 2011b as well).

I save this figure by `File-> Save As...-> test.eps`.
But when I use LaTeX to generate `.pdf` file with this piece of code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
test1
\begin{figure}
 \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[height=140mm]{test.eps}
 \end{center}
\end{figure}
test2
\end{document}
```

I use xelatex to compile my `.tex` file, and got a pdf like this

[image: .eps shown at wrong position]

The `.eps` file is shown at wrong position. "center" seems to be useless. I have done other tests, which prove that `.eps` file generated by other software(Word, Adobe Acrobat) can be shown correctly. Therefore, I think the problem may lie in Matlab. Perhaps the `.eps` file generated by Matlab is not compatible with some tex package.

This subtle problem has wasted me much time. Does anybody know why and how to solve the problem ?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Note that instead of `\begin{center}...\end{center}` you better use `\centering`. This does not solve your problem, though.

Comment: It's due to the stupid bounding box declaration in the .eps file. Becaue it is matlab being itself. You can open it in GSView and export it again by clicking on its true bounding box. I would use pgfplots for plotting directly for that though.

Comment: Related [How to avoid large margins around Matlab plot in PDF](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5559/15717) and Also [What is the best way to include Matlab graphics?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3995/15717)

Comment: Both of @texenthusiast's links mention export_fig which can be found on the MATLAB Central File Exchange website.  It fixes many of the problems inherent in MATLAB's rather poor built-in EPS and PDF rendering engines.

Comment: Why not just produce the PDF directly from matlab?

Comment: @LostBrit Yes, .pdf produced by matlab can be shown correctly as far as its horizontal and vertical position is concerned. But .pdf has big margins. I will have to strip the margins,

Comment: @texenthusiast I find a solution of matlab2tikz at your links. .tikz file generated by matlab2tikz can be shown correctly.

Comment: So is the issue really that you can't generate a good PDF with matlab? @craigim already suggested ways to deal with that. You need to adjust the paper size, and that's about it. If needed I can post a full answer describing this (or link to several others, probably).

Comment: In my experience, you can generate decent pdf/eps with MATLAB, and if you dig deep, you can generate good pdf/eps, but you can't produce great pdf/eps.  For instance, if the plot contains raster images (such as a contour plot), it rasters the fonts as well.  If you force it into a vector format, it replaces the fonts (see [Choosing a printer driver](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/choosing-a-printer-driver.html) for details).

Comment: Maybe related: the thread ["eps inclusion by dvipdfmx and xdvipdfmx"](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2013-May/033670.html) in mailing list for TeX Live last month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will just try to give you a quick push. If I recall correctly `\begin{center}` puts the center of the coordinate system which is left lower corner of your picture (think of picture being in the first quadrant) at the center of the page. That is exactly what I see on your figure. Did you play with moving things left down etc? I do not have now to check right now but I would be very, very surprised to see that MATLAB doesn't produce correct `eps` file (that it does not compute correct Bounding Boxes). You can always export figure as PostScript and then use something [ps2eps](http://www.tm.uka.de/~bless/ps2eps.html) to produce correct Bounding Boxes for those `eps` files and filters some special postscript command sequences that can produce erroneous results.

Comment: You can be very very surprised. It's been like that since matlab 6.5 and I've reported it a few times.

Comment: @percusse I would be damned!!! That thing is so expensive! I can not believe. These days I moved almost 100% to Python so I do not use it often. What happen if you export figure in PostScript and then use ps2eps to convert? It might be just those stupid Bounding Boxes.

Comment: Exactly. I moved to Python too.

Comment: [Spyder](https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/): Interesting Python IDE similar to MATLAB

Comment: @percusse I third the move to Python!

Comment: @texenthusiast I do not like IDEs! They tend to try to shield users from having to learn about the work flow. I like to know what I am doing. For Python I use IPython as a shell and just my beloved nvi editor. I tried IPython workbook and didn't like a bit. I think I tested Canvas on my daughter's MAC (I use OpenBSD).  It didn't work for me.

Comment: [scipy](http://scipy.org/Getting_Started#head-29c5ff005c7f21eb9e5e19c850159cdfd80a39ed) here , it's for interesting folks

Comment: I have used scipy and numpy a few days ago, but they are so slow...I tested python and matlab with exactly same program, and it turned out that python need 10 times more time than matlab.

Comment: @user31469 Comparing apples and oranges. Python is general purpose programming language vs MATLAB task oriented language. Sure MATLAB is well optimized (Fortran under the hood) for some things but for somethings not even usable. However the cost of MATLAB and few tool boxes is prohibitive for most but corporate customers.

Comment: Adding captions is really irritating.. Sometimes i would overwrite the matlab generated `eps` with inkscape to fix the problems with the files. But it distorts the `imagesc` figures: they become blurry. I am beginning to loathe matlab