# How to export Visio graphic for Tex document?

Tags: graphics, pdf

Visio can export many different image formats but only `.emf` and `.pdf` as vector graphics. Tex can only handle `.eps` and `.pdf` vector graphics and therefor `.pdf` is the file format to go.

But there is the problem. All PDF exports allways have a big white margin around them and can't be imported in Tex like this.

**How to export a Visio graphic properly to use it in Tex?**

Comment: For a general way to crop PDF files (not just from Visio), use the `pdfcrop` command line utility as described here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5559/how-to-avoid-large-margins-around-matlab-plot-in-pdf

Comment: I usually do the exporting by doing a print and saving it to a PDF. The important part tough is that remember to increase the resolution and disable any compression before hitting the print button. And then include the PDF in your latex.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about Visio not about TeX.

Comment: How to remove the margin for Visio is completely off topic. This question should have been closed.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Actually you are wrong. Reading this question with it's answers after the fact does look like off-topic but this question actually looks for a solution within Tex. I couldn't find any and therefore posted my workaround outside of Tex. But this is not the desired solution. Therefore this question is actually not off-topic. It was made off-topic by the existing answers or the lack of solutions within tex. But as moha showed in ins answer (4h ago) there is a tex solution to this problem.

Comment: So tge question is how to trim or clip a pdf file and is not related to Visio at all and is probably a duplicate.

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes, could be.

Comment: @Spen: You question is: **How to export a Visio graphic properly to use it in Tex?** If you want to ask: *How can I crop a PDF graphics, e. g., exported with Visio?* you should have asked this. As long as you ask, how to export something from Visio, I'll say: it is off-topic.

Comment: @Schweinebacke It is often not easy to formulate the problem you are having and the solution you are searching for. What I searched for was a solution in Tex but yes, this wasn't formulated well. I have no problem with this question getting flaggt as duplicate to a "how to crop" question. At least everyone with the same problem, searching with the same bad formulation would find a solution.

Comment: What you are describing is in fact a Visio problem. So maybe it should not have been asked in a TeX-related forum. But I just found out how to solve it in Visio 2016: Before exporting the PDF, select you whole drawing. Then in the export options select "Page range -> Selection". The created PDF page will still have the same dimensions as your Visio page, but the weird border around the page is not there!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem.

I found a simple way to deal with it.

- Save the chart as svg file by Visio.
- open the svg file by Inkscape.
- Save as the .pdf format
- On the next pop up window:

  - Embed Fonts
  - Use exported object's size
  - Margin 0.1
- click ok

Next the generated pdf file will be imported by latex easily as same as png or eps.

---

But some times inkscape does not read the svg file properly and some mistakes are occurred. In this case the solution which works great and mentioned above is:

- save the pdf file by visio
- include the pdf file in latex
- use trim for cropping the figure in latex

for example:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth, trim={1cm 3cm 1cm 8cm},clip]{Fig.pdf}
```

Comment: I am sometimes terrified that it is 2022 and we still need to deal with these basic problems with such complicated solutions - thank you for sharing though!

Answer (score 8):

I was searching for a solution for some time so it's probably usefull for someone else.

You have to do the following in the same order:

In Visio:

1. Go to options and open Customize Ribbon
2. Add the developertools to the menu
3. Go to the developer tab and open Show ShapeSheet -> Print Properties
4. Edit PageLeftMargin, PageRightMargin, PageTopMargin and PageBottomMargin to 1
5. Fit to Drawing using Design-->Size-->Fit to Drawing
6. Export PDF
7. options -> current page & don't show background
8. Save PDF file

In Tex as usual:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{graphic.pdf}
    \caption{graphic} \label{fig:graphic}
\end{figure}
```

I hope this helps someone else struggling with this problem.