# MATLAB plots in LyX

Tags: graphics, lyx, matlab

I am very new to LyX or LaTeX, so I do not want to complicate the process. So what I currently do, is saving the figure as a PDF and then attaching it. But I don't think this is a good method as the output I am getting looks like this:

[image]

Is there any easy way to do this?
The settings are as follow:
Placement: Here Definitely
Alignment: Center

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34386/how-to-export-matlab-figures-to-pdf-latex?rq=1

Comment: Standard PDF export from Matlab is kind of rubbish, open the PDF and see, there's probably a lot of whitespace around the plot.  There are functions on the File Exchange that does it better I think, e.g. [`export_fig`](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) See also [How to avoid large margins around Matlab plot in PDF](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5559)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you mean is that you want the figure to be located neatly with the caption "Figure 1 My lovely MATLAB plot" under it, right ?

In that case you need to insert->float->figure

This will create a floating environment for the figure, with a caption. You should add "My MATLAB plot" there.[image: adding float]

Then you'd want to add your figure, go to before the caption and do Insert->graphics

in the file menu add the pdf image you created[image: plot GUI]

You can also scale the image by setting its width or height. After you add the plot you'll see something like this in Lyx[image: in lyx]

and when previewing you'll get the following in the pdf
[image]

Also - you should consider using eps files instead of pdf, matlab exports them just as easily and they tend to scale better