# How to convert PDF to EPS?

Tags: pdf, conversion, eps

I can't find a tool to convert PDF to EPS, neither in MikTeX nor in TeXLive. Is there such a tool actually?

---

**Update:**

Based on Herbert's accepted answer, I simplify his batch as follows:

```shell
#!/bin/sh
# $Id: pdf2eps,v 0.01 2005/10/28 00:55:46 Herbert Voss Exp $
# Convert PDF to encapsulated PostScript.
# usage:
# pdf2eps <page number> <pdf file without ext>

pdfcrop "$2.pdf" "$2-temp.pdf"
pdftops -f $1 -l $1 -eps "$2-temp.pdf" "$2.eps"
rm  "$2-temp.pdf"
```

For Windows users, create a batch file, name it `pdf2eps.bat` as follows:

```
rem pdf2eps <page number> <pdf file without ext>
echo off
pdfcrop "%2.pdf" "%2-temp.pdf"
pdftops -f %1 -l %1 -eps "%2-temp.pdf" "%2.eps"
del  "%2-temp.pdf"
```

Comment: @xport: The way I see it, is that `can't` belongs to `find a converter` while `neither` belongs to `MikTeX nor TeXLive` and not to `can or can't find`.

Comment: @Peter: I see, but also note that people there point out that the original sentence doesn't sound natural (comment of Unreason) and can be confusing (Martha's answer). So I would suggest to write "I can't find a converter to convert PDF to EPS either in MikTeX or TeXLive" (as suggested in the TeX.SX thread). Also "converter to convert" doesn't sound good. Anyway, instead of starting a lengthly discussion here, just change the text back. Edits from the moderators are not carved in stone or in any way binding.

Comment: @Martin We are in violent agreement!

Comment: @Alan: Thanks! I fully agree with the "can't" and the comma. The original "can" version is just too confusing.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Here is a Linux script `pdf2eps`. It can easily be translated into a batch script for Windows.

```
#!/bin/sh
# $Id: pdf2eps,v 0.01 2005/10/28 00:55:46 Herbert Voss Exp $
# Convert PDF to encapsulated PostScript.
# usage:
# pdf2eps <page number> <pdf file without ext>

pdfcrop $2.pdf
pdftops -f $1 -l $1 -eps "$2-crop.pdf" 
rm  "$2-crop.pdf"
mv  "$2-crop.eps" $2.eps
```

Comment: I see. I forget to include the `--gscmd gswin64c` because I have 2 ghostscript installed.

Comment: To make sure that the script works with arguments that include a space I'd recommend to put all references for `$1` and `$2` in double quotes, like so: `"$2.pdf"`.

Comment: no, spaces in filenames should _not_ be supported ...

Comment: If any of the commands fails, the script will continue, while it shouldn't. Put `set -e` in the beginning.

Comment: This solution produced a very low quality output (e.g. compared to the Inkscape solution suggested by Martin Scharrer).

Comment: simply use the optional argument  `-dNOCACHE`

Answer (score 101):

Providing such a tool is not the task of a TeX distribution. You need to use an external tool.

There are a couple of them which should be able to convert PDF to EPS, sometimes by going over PS first.

I can recommend the following 3 tools which produce nice results for me:

- Inkscape (Vector graphic editor, free & multi-platform)

Can be either used using the GUI (open PDF, save as EPS) or using [the command line](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/Using_the_Command_Line#Export_files) (tested under Linux only):

`inkscape input.pdf --export-eps=output.eps`

```
inkscape input.pdf --export-filename=output.eps
```

- Acrobat Reader (Linux Version) + `ps2eps` (TeXLive)

  ```
  acroread -toPostScript input.pdf
  ps2eps input.ps
  ```
- Ghostscript (multi-platform)
  Note: `-dNOCACHE` is needed to prevent GhostScript from rastering the fonts.
  `eps2write` was formerly used as `epswrite`.

  ```
  gs -q -dNOCACHE -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=eps2write -sOutputFile=output.eps input.pdf
  ```

There are also the following tools. I didn't tested all of them and some raster the fonts :-( !

- ImageMagick `convert` (which might use Ghostscript itself. Calling it manually if more flexible and might avoid issues. `convert` might actually raster the PDF!)

  ```
  convert input.pdf output.eps
  ```
- `pdf2ps` (uses Ghostscript) + `ps2eps` (comes with TeXLive)
- `pdftops` (part of [`poppler`](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/)), use the `-eps` switch for EPS output.

and most likely more.

Comment: @xport: See my update, simple use the `pdf2ps` wrapper script.

Comment: Of these options, I recommend `pdftops`, using the format `pdftops -level3 -eps file.pdf file.eps`. The result isn't quite strictly EPS for some reason though. I pipe through `sed '2s/^/%/'` to force the proper double % comment format for the second line (most tools do not care about this, but some might).

Comment: @xport: Thanks, I accidentally put this to `pdf2ps` while it belongs to `pdftops`.

Comment: @Martin: So how can `pdf2ps` produce `eps`?

Comment: @xport: I added a Ghostscript command now. You could copy `pdf2ps` to `pdf2eps` which is a shell script and replace the output device `ps2write` to `epswrite`. It's basically the same as the command above just with a nicer interface.

Comment: @Martin: GhostScript changes the fonts to raster format that is very bad.

Comment: @xport: ImageMagick most likely just calls GhostScript internally. For GhostScript there might be further options to be set to avoid that issue. However, I now tested `acroread -toPostScript` + `ps2eps` and it seems to produce vector graphics and fonts.

Comment: @xport: I now figure out that Inkscape allows for command line arguments to directly convert formats. I added the command. It runs under Windows, Mac and Linux!

Comment: @xport: I found out that `inkscape` support command line arguments for conversion. It produces nice results! It is also able to produce SVG which are nice for online content.

Comment: +1 for the reference to Inkscape which produced the best results for me in Windows.

Comment: It looks like ghostscript's eps driver is now called eps2write (I've got version 9.15, not sure when it changed). Otherwise the command still works!

Comment: on OSX, the convert shell program worked for me: "convert a.pdf a.eps"

Comment: In my tests, on OS X the `convert` command isn't actually keeping things resolution independent (it appears to do a high-resolution raster). My file size blew up by a factor of 20 and zooming in in preview showed artifacts. Using `pdf2ps` followed by `ps2eps` kept the file size under 1MB and preserved the quality.

Comment: Great! How can I use **Ghostscript** to transform, say a 30 pages PDF file to corresponding 30 `.eps` files(i.e. 1 page with 1 `eps`)? Is there a way to automatically do it? I want to change the output(that PDF) file of LaTeX to many `.eps` files that each can be imported in InDesign (one page, one `eps`) to do the further adjustment and decorations.

Comment: `epswrite` does seem to be deprecated. `eps2write` can be used instead. See also this bug report: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=798682

Comment: Inkscape changes the fonts of my pdf. Is there an option to avoid that?

Comment: @Zach: Sorry, No idea. Are the fonts embedded in the PDF? Check the inkscape Manual.

Comment: On Linux with `inkscape` I got best results. `gs` result had very sharp font edges.

Comment: For me, the only tool that would NOT raster my file was `acroread`. With ghostscript, whatever I tried resulting in an image embedded in an EPS file, which is not what I want. My PDF doesn't (or at least shouldn't) contain anything fancy like alpha transparency that cannot be represented in postscript - it's a simple black and white line graphic and a bit of text.

Comment: `acroread` DOES seem to produce a slightly weird file, though - when I tried to convert it to EPS with `ps2eps`, `gv` would afterwards only show the bottom half of my figure. I managed to fix that with  the `--ignoreBB` option of `ps2eps`, which seems to make it ignore the bounding box in the PS file, and recompute a new one.

Comment: For me on Linux, `pdftops` rasters fonts, where `gs` doesn't (with the mentioned flag).

Answer (score 13):

I've tried a number of options, including converting with Inkscape and using pdftops with the eps flag turned on.  Both have problems with certain fonts.  The online tools and ImageMagick both rasterize the image unacceptably.

I found that the most effective process is to convert in two steps: first convert the .pdf to .ps using pdftops, which preserves the fonts and doesn't rasterize the image.  Next, convert the .ps to .eps using ps2eps (comes with the TeXLive distro).

A bash script I use to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Convert PDF to encapsulated PostScript
# usage: pdf2eps <filename.pdf>

# Remove .pdf extension from input
filename=$(echo $1 | sed 's/.pdf//')
# Convert into .eps
pdftops $filename.pdf $filename-temp.ps
ps2eps $filename-temp.ps
mv $filename-temp.eps $filename.eps
rm $filename-temp.ps
```

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, the EPS format [does not handle transparency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_%28graphic%29#Transparency_in_PostScript). If the PDF source file includes transparency, then the tools listed above will rasterize the image in the EPS output, leading to pixelation and larger file sizes. One possible solution is to use an EPS file with non-standard extensions ([link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24287/36665)).

Conversion from PDF to EPS *can* be achieved without pixelation using the Adobe Acrobat software. I selected `Save As...`, and then `Format -> Encapsulated Postscript`. Under `Settings...` I have noticed that the `General -> Binary` option slightly reduces file size. On OS X, I find that `Color Management -> Color Profile -> Apple RGB` preserves screen display colors. The output EPS file is larger than the PDF source, but otherwise looks the same to me.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the best method to convert PDFs to eps files is to use a conventional PDF reader (Acrobat or Okular) to print the PDF to a file with the extension eps. More specifically,  I used the usual option "print to file" available in the print dialog window and changed the extension of the destination file to eps. I tried it and it works very well and conserves to a large scale the quality of the document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What have one to do to follow your solution? Can you explain more please, for example what did you exactly when you tried it?

Comment: As it stands, it is not a real answer, but more like a comment

Comment: Hi Farid, can you please edit your answer add this information to it?  Otherwise it could be that your answer will be converted to a comment (see comment of @Christian Hupfer). A valid answer should have a description that leads to a solution, if a reader follows it.  Your answer until now does it not.

Answer (score 3):

Copied from http://www.iml.ece.mcgill.ca/~stephan/oopdf2eps

It worked very well

```
#!/bin/bash

TARGET=${1%.pdf}.eps
echo "pdftops -eps ${1} - | ps2eps > ${TARGET}"
pdftops -eps ${1} - | ps2eps > ${TARGET}
echo "ps2eps stdout redirected to: ${TARGET}"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really experienced with scripts, so I did it "manually".

1. Open the pdf in Inkscape
2. Rasterize the file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> or File -> Rasterize). This option can export to `.png` only but after you get png file you can easily convert it to `.eps` or any picture file type. The options of picture resolution and picture size are available.

I know that this way is not optimal and probably don't suit any case, but it took less time than to learn how to use the scripts mentioned above and to test them.

P.S. BTW, most online pdf-to-eps tools works ugly.

Comment: "not optimal" is a nice expression, when you smash vector graphics to bitmaps.

Answer (score 2):

Most solutions rasterize the PDF-file resulting in large files. In my case, inkscape failed because some characters are missing (ligatures like ff, fl). Acroread worked in one case, the other failed because of a wrong bounding box.

My solution was, to use the document viewer (Ubuntu 13.10) and to print the document into a file with the Postscript-option (the resulting file is vector based). The postscript file could be converted with ps2eps.

Comment: awesome solution.

Answer (score 1):

`pdftops` sometimes messes up the bounding box. I use Adobe Illustrator to get the job done. The file size is usually 5 times larger.

I know it is a heavy and expensive tool for a simple job, but if you do have it already, why not use it. :)

Answer (score 1):

On Windows (with gsview installed) I do the following:

1. Open file.pdf in gsview.
2. File/Select/Convert and choose 'epswrite' as your Device.
3. Pat yourself on the back.

Comment: Using gsview worked the best for me, as mentioned by Brent Farwick. I just want to add that having -dNOCACHE as an option avoided to raster the fonts and allowed to get perfect result.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with most of the above-mentioned options and all produced a significant decrease in quality. I found it very well to open the .pdf in Okular and then "save as" (don't export) as pdf but you manipulate the file extension to .eps.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!