# Why does my EPS header have % Produced by xpdf/pdftops 3.02pl4?

Tags: eps, paper-size, units, bounding-box, epstool

I have a simple input file contains PSTricks code as follows.

```
% sample.tex
\documentclass[cmyk]{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[paperwidth=144bp,paperheight=108bp,margin=0bp]{geometry}

\parindent=0bp
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(\paperwidth,\paperheight)
\psframe[linecolor=red](\paperwidth,\paperheight)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

It is compiled using:

```
latex -interaction=nonstopmode %1
dvips -R -t unknown %1
ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages#/None -dCompatibilityLevel#1.5 -dPDFSETTINGS#/prepress %1.ps
pdftops -level3 -eps %1.pdf %1-temp.eps
epstool --copy --bbox %1-temp.eps %1.eps
```

Before invoking the epstool, my `sample-temp.eps` contains the following:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
% Produced by xpdf/pdftops 3.02pl4
%%Creator: dvips(k) 5.99 Copyright 2010 Radical Eye Software
%%Title: sample.dvi
%%LanguageLevel: 2
%%DocumentSuppliedResources: (atend)
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 144 108
%%EndComments
%%BeginProlog
%%BeginResource: procset xpdf 3.02pl4 0
%%Copyright: Copyright 1996-2007 Glyph & Cog, LLC
```

Note: I don't understand why the second row does not exist in Herbert's EPS.

I failed to execute `epstool` because the second row has a single `%` that should be `%%`. The following screenshot shows the error log.

[image]

---

Based on Lev's comment, I tried to add `-level3` switch to `pdftops`, but it still does not solve the problem. I don't understand what `sed` in Lev's comment, what is that?

This is my `pdftops` version:

[image]

Comment: I gave the solution to this problem in a comment on [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20883/how-to-convert-pdf-to-eps/20884#20884)

Comment: using `-leve3` is nonsense, nearly all printers do not have this level installed

Comment: I see, that is the one which uses the `xpdf` lib, don't know if there is a version with `poppler` for Windows.

Comment: @xport: On Linux the command isn't part of TeXLive because it is already there.

Comment: @Herbert. Indeed most printers do not use level3. However most people are using `pdftoeps` to produce postscript for later conversion to a different format, most often because they are integrating with a postscript-based journal publisher workflow, that will later be distilled to PDF for distribution. Anyway, my comment here was in relation to using `sed` to fix the missing `%`.

Comment: @xport: `sed` is a tool to automate editing text files. See for example [the manual page.](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) The `sed` program `2s/^/%/` means "add a `%` at the beginning of the second line". (The `-level3` is not important for your current problem but it can produce very much smaller .eps files under some circumstances.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my eps:

```
 %%BoundingBox: 0 0 145 109
 %%HiResBoundingBox: 0.000 0.000 144.000 108.000
```

with the above sequence under Linux

```
voss@shania:~/Documents> epstool --bbox --copy latex6-temp.eps latex6.eps 
"gs"  -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=bbox   -c "<</PageSize [9400 9400] /PageOffset [3000 3000]>> setpagedevice" -f "/tmp/gsviewuW8XZu"
GPL Ghostscript  9.00 (2010-09-14)
Copyright (C) 2010 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
%%BoundingBox: 3000 3000 3145 3109
%%HiResBoundingBox: 3000.000073 3000.000073 3144.000490 3108.000491


voss@shania:~> epstool --help
epstool 3.08 2005-06-06
Copyright 1995-2005 Ghostgum Software Pty Ltd
Usage: epstool command [options] inputfile outputfile
```

The header of `<file>-temp.eps` with a modified bbox (doen by hand)

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%Creator: dvips(k) 5.991 Copyright 2011 Radical Eye Software
%%LanguageLevel: 2
%%DocumentSuppliedResources: (atend)
%%BoundingBox: 72 72 72 72
%%DocumentSuppliedResources: (atend)
%%EndComments
%%BeginProlog
%%BeginResource: procset xpdf 3.00 0
%%Copyright: Copyright 1996-2004 Glyph & Cog, LLC
```

and the `pdftops` version:

```
voss@shania:~> pdftops --help
pdftops version 0.12.4
Copyright 2005-2009 The Poppler Developers - http://poppler.freedesktop.org
Copyright 1996-2004 Glyph & Cog, LLC
Usage: pdftops [options] <PDF-file> [<PS-file>]
```

Comment: I can confirm it. `epstool 3.08 2005-06-06`. BTW I think it is pretty stupid that BBox is enlarged by `epstool` for no good reason.

Comment: @xport: epstool recalculates the bounding box, this is why the program is used ...

Comment: @xport's comment was meant as a joke, but there was no reduction (possibly another typo or I read it wrongly) -- BBox was enlarged and HiResBBox is the same as original BBox, which is strange at least (BBox > HiResBBox part, because it could be easily set to exact size).

Comment: @xport: `sample-temp.eps` has `%%BoundingBox: 0 0 144 108`. I believe Herbert has the same line.

Comment: @xport: It's not only Herbert's EPS. I confirmed it I have the same lines there, thus it's only you who have different values. :) My hunch is that it works the other way, i.e. first HiResBBox is calced and then BBox, where maybe some really strange rounding is used.

Comment: @Herbert: But it doesn't explain the difference between HiResBBox and BBox, unless `epstool` uses internally VeryHiResBBox...

Comment: @xport: See my output. For a test I set by hand before running epstool the bounding box to `72 72 72 72`. However, as can be seen it makes sense that bonding boxes differ (in this case) by 1 pt

Comment: @xport: `epstool` calls here `"gs"  -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=bbox   -c "<</PageSize [9400 9400] /PageOffset [3000 3000]>> setpagedevice" -f "/tmp/gsviewV5k9IZ"` and below copyright line outputs `%%BoundingBox: 3000 3000 3145 3109
%%HiResBoundingBox: 3000.000073 3000.000073 3144.000490 3108.000491
OK`

Comment: @xport: can you update your gs version to at least 9.00?

Comment: @xport: see edited answer. I didn't run it again, so it shows the manipulated bbox for my test.

Comment: @xport: I suppose your version of `pdftops` uses the `xpdf` library. My version uses the `poppler lib`. My `pdftops` is version 0.12.4