# Convert PDF figures to PS figures without pixelation

Tags: pdf, conversion, ghostscript, ps

I have a tex document (called foo.tex) that includes several PDF figures. I need to generate a PostScript version as well as a PDF version of the final document. Running `pdflatex foo.tex` works just fine and outputs a normal foo.pdf file. However, when I run `pdf2ps foo.pdf`, most of the pages are fine, except for a few that come out extremely pixelated. The pages that come out pixelated are also the pages with the most complicated PDF figures. I tracked the problem down to the pdf-to-ps conversion of these troublesome figures. When I run `pdftops` on them separately, the fonts turn out pixelated, even though they are the exact same fonts in my other figures (which turn out fine).

If it's useful, I'm using Mac OS X (and Fedora on a different machine) and my fonts are all Type 1 fonts.

How do I convert my PDF figures to PS figures without pixelation?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That's what I eventually resorted to, but the conversion is still ugly and changes the fonts (although they aren't as bad). Thought there must be a more principled solution.

Comment: You mention `pdf2ps` and also `pdftops`. Is it a typo or you are using two different programs? If so, did you try different combinations of those?

Comment: What is the source of the pdf figures? pdf format is more or less a container for nearly all and everything. If the source are bitmaps, you can't expect much.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20884/19356 helps?

Comment: This seems to be about GhostScript rather than TeX: at best borderline for us. Without seeing the PDFs or sources it's also pretty tricky to answer. So I'm minded to close either as off-topic or too localized.

Comment: No feedback to date, so I am going to close as 'too localized' (without a concrete demo I'm not keen on migrating to a more suitable site).