# pdf figure latex without pdflatex

Tags: graphics, pdftex

I have a figure only in pdf to include in a big tex file that doesn't compile with pdflatex. Is there a way to include a pdf graphic in normal latex?

Alternatively, can I convert the pdf to eps without losing quality?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: [XY](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2449/5763): Why does the file not compile with pdfLaTeX?

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer for your first question is `No.' The reason for that is the standard output link of plain TeX goes:

TeX → Dvi → PS

For this historical reason, the dvi format only supports postscript specials, and inclusion of postscript graphic.

So, the problem boils down to: [How to convert PDF to EPS?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20883/how-to-convert-pdf-to-eps)

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I converted with coreldraw or adobe illustrator and the conversion was perfect. Much better than the one from inkscape.

Comment: That's wrong: We still have `dvipdfm`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I am not sure what actually `dvipdfm` does. Acording to this: http://mintaka.sdsu.edu/GF/bibliog/latex/LaTeXtoPDF.html, and my few-years-ago experience it required eps figures. I would expect it interprets postscript specials, and include (translate?) them in the resulting pdf.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Sorry, so you were right, it has also an ability to include pdf or other images (see http://gaspra.kettering.edu/dvipdfm/). So, your solution is probably the best option, if the final output is to be pdf.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: Use `latex` (which will be `pdftex` in dvi-mode) and [`dvipdfm`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/dvipdfm).

Answer (score 1):

Download Inkscape [here](http://inkscape.org)

You can convert pdf to eps and viceversa

Comment: I tried that and I still lose a little of the quality. But I guess it is the only way… Thanks!!!