# How to convert the figures in ps/pdf obtained from tex to eps

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to convert the figures in ps/pdf obtained from tex to eps so that is mathematical symbols remains intact.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%x=2cm,y=2cm
        dot/.style = {circle, fill,
                      inner sep=.3ex,
                      }
                            ]
    \draw[-latex, thick, draw=black] (0,0)--(1,0) node [right] {$x$};
    \draw[-latex, thick, draw=black] (0,0)--(0,1) node [above] {$y$};
    \draw[scale=1,red,fill=red] (0, 0) circle (.3ex);
        \draw[scale=1] (0, 0) node[anchor=north east]{$O$} ;
        \draw[<<-,line width=2,blue] (0,1) -- (1,1) node[right]{$(x_0,y_0)$};
        %\draw[middlearrow={stealth reversed},line width=2,blue] (0,4) -- (3,4) 
        \draw[scale=1,red,fill=red] (1,1) circle (.3ex);
               \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Problem 1: Using some online converter (online-convert.com), the comma in $(x_0,y_0)$ is not coming properly. I have attached the jpg of the eps file (tex to ps by texniccenter then ps to eps online).

Problem 2: I want to make the mathematical symbols $(x_0,y_0)$ bigger in size. How it is possible?

[image]

Comment: Try the command line `pdftops -eps <PDF file>`, which should generate a `.eps` without problem.

Comment: @Werner In windows, is it possible?

Comment: If you have Miktex then `ps2eps` should be installed, which you can use from the Command Prompt.

Comment: Related: [How to convert PDF to EPS?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20883/5764)

Comment: For increasing the size of the coordinates, you can use `\scalebox{<num>}{<coords>}`, where `<num>` is the scaling factor. For example, `\scalebox{2}{$(x_0,y_0)$}` would double the size of the entire coordinate object.

Answer (score 2):

Both `pdftops` (with the `-eps` switch) and `ps2eps` are distributed with [MiKTeX](//miktex.org/download) and [TeX Live](//www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html). You can find these in the `/bin` folder and use them from the command line to convert either PDF or PS output to EPS.