# How to convert pdf to eps in windows

Tags: eps, pdftops

I want to convert a pdf file to eps using windows file has mathematical symbols and I want to make then unaltered.

Getting help from here, I have made a bat file and placed the bat file (pdf2eps) in say D drive

```
rem pdf2eps <page number> <pdf file without ext>
echo off
pdfcrop "%2.pdf" "%2-temp.pdf"
pdftops -f %1 -l %1 -eps "%2-temp.pdf" "%2.eps"
del  "%2-temp.pdf"
```

What will be the next steps. Please write the full steps to get an eps from a pdf.

Edit: Changing directory to the path of pdf2eps.bat in cmd.exe, I have tried with  pdf2eps 1 oldfile (without pdf extension).
Also tried with pdftoeps -eps <PDF file with .pdf>
But not get any result by both process. What to do?

Comment: Wrong site? This hasn't really to do with TeX, does it?

Comment: @campa https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20883/how-to-convert-pdf-to-eps?rq=1

Comment: Well, we are a very tolerant and open-minded community `:-)` What is the problem with the solutions described there?

Comment: @campa After saving bat file I need to know the steps. I am unable to convert. Thank you.

Comment: this is a duplicate (and off topic) so it will be closed here, but you just need to put the bat file in a directory in your path and then change folder to where the pdf is and type `pdf2eps  1 oldfile`  to convert page 1 of `oldfile.pdf` to `oldfile.eps`. But why do you want an eps file?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I want the eps to use in tex. Is there any other option?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Changing directory to the path of pdf2eps.bat iin cmd.exe, I have tried with your pdf2eps  1 oldfile  (without pdf extension) but not get any result. Also tried with pdftoeps -eps <PDF file with .pdf>

Comment: this really isn't the right forum to explain windows commandline usage. assuming pdftoeps is in your path cd to the directory with the pdf file and type `pdftoeps yourfilename`  if the command isn't in your path then you will need to give the full path to the command. But you should be in the directory with the pdf file

Comment: why do you want an eps?????, by _far_ the most common thing tex users do with eps files is convert them to pdf so they can include them into a document with pdflatex. Why do you need to convert the other way?