# Vector images in PDF

Tags: latexmk, vector

I use [`latexmk`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) to automatically generate my LaTeX files. I want to use vector graphics, exported from Matlab (*.eps) but I know, that this is not possible (for some reason) - just image files like *.jpg or *.png. Is there a way to tell latexmk to workaround that drawback or will there be no vector graphics for me in near future?

Sorry in case I bring up the issue again - but after quite some time with LaTeX it's still not clear to me...

Comment: `latexmk` doesn't *generate* LaTeX files, but *compiles* them to DVI/PS or PDF. You can use PDF images instead of EPS. Simply convert them using `eps2pdf` or similar. See the question [What are good ways to convert EPS to PDF?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2872/what-are-good-ways-to-convert-eps-to-pdf).

Comment: According to the [Mathworks MATLAB reference on Export Formats](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/print.html#export_formats), exporting directly to EPS is possible, and so is exporting to PDF and SVG. So you don't (shouldn't!) need any work-around.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please keep your questions short an precise. There is no need for openings, closings, signatures or gratitude. In the case of external tools, simply link to there websites like I did now. Thanks and Happy TeXing!

Comment: See also [What is the best way to include Matlab graphics?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3995/what-is-the-best-way-to-include-matlab-graphics)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can still export from Matlab in EPS format, if you need this for other purposes and load the **epstopdf** package that, in recent TeX distributions, will spawn an on-the-fly conversion:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
```

On the other hand, directly exporting in PDF from Matlab could be the faster solution.

Comment: My last attempts to export figures directly to pdf by means of builtin matlab tools was a disaster. Eventually, I wrote a script which always took the `fig -> eps -> pdf` route. If I am not mistaken, matlab failed to produce bounding boxes for the pdf exports. But perhaps this has been solved in recent matlab versions (my information is two years old).

Comment: I should have said that I used `print -depsc <filename>` or `print -dpdf <filename>` in matlab.