# How to use `epstopdf` in batch mode?

Tags: pdf, eps, epstopdf

The top voted answer to the following question is a really good way to convert `eps` files to `pdf`.
[What are good ways to convert EPS to PDF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2872/what-are-good-ways-to-convert-eps-to-pdf)
I really prefer it over `ps2pdf` because it preserves the size of the image.

However, I am unable to employ it as a batch-conversion tool. The command `epstopdf -h` yields `epstopdf: -h: unknown option` and I couldn't find any other options to configure it for a batch mode. I think I will write a small `Python` script but wanted to use a simpler option.

**Edit1:**
What I am looking for is an option which will be similar to the following command.
`epstopdf "C:\path\to\image\folder with spaces\*.eps"`

The `for` loop doesn't work here because of the spaces in the path.

Comment: `epstopdf --help`

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately batch-conversion is not an option. :(

Comment: do you mean something like `for i in *.eps; do epstopdf $i; done`

Comment: `epstopdf` does not have an *interactive* mode, therefore it is always in *batch* mode.

Comment: `ps2pdf -dEPSCrop` preserves the size of the image (defined by the bounding box) for real EPS files.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Maybe Shashank meant the possibility of doing something like `epstopdf *.eps`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There's a space in the path, so when I tried the loop it correctly tries for all the files without the "". Therefore I still get the error `too many input files`.

Comment: @ShashankSawant `for i in *.eps; do epstopdf "$i"; done` you need to quote filenames with spaces, that's just general shell syntax, nothing to do with epstopdf

Comment: Sorry about that one! Yeah.. it works. I think I should accept Heiko's answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Windows

Quotes should be used in a Windows command window to protect the spaces:

```batch
for %f in ("C:\path\to\image\folder with spaces\*.eps") do epstopdf "%f"
```

Inside a `.bat` file, the percent needs to be doubled.

### Linux/bash

Special characters like spaces can be escaped with the backslash in `bash`:

```bash
for f in /path/to/image/folder\ with\ spaces/*.eps; do epstopdf "$f"; done
```

Alternatively quotes can be used for the spaces. The joker characters should be outside of the quotes. The following example also uses several lines for
readability:

```bash
for f in "/path/to/image/folder with spaces/"*.eps; do
    epstopdf "$f"
done
```

Comment: Linux (Bash) version? Thanks.

Comment: @becko I have added a version for `bash`.