# Should I include image or pdf to speed up compiling time?

Tags: beamer, pdf

I am preparing some slides and I need to include some photos and because of that, it takes a long time. So, overleaf runs out of time and can't compile it. I am wondering if I should include all photos as png files or import pdf files and then crop them?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/523758/133968.

Comment: No idea, try both options and measure how long it takes

Comment: Two points: png is one of the most difficult formats for latex to include and if the images are really photos (and not say diagram), then png is the most unsuitable format. Photos as png become verrrrry large. That being said, if you plan to just embed the pngs in pdfs and then include these, this isn't  much better. Can you show us an example of your images so we can advice on a suitable file format?