# Using psfrag with pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, pstricks, psfrag

Is there any way of using `psfrag` with pdflatex?
It seems fairly similar to the problem of using `pstricks` with pdflatex.
Do they both depend on the same things, or does `psfrag` include `pstricks`?

Can I assume that if I use one of the workarounds to make `pstricks` work, the same workaround would do for `psfrag`?
Is there an equivalent of `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}` that will work for `psfrag`?

I realise there are a few questions here rather than just one, but they all share the overall question of how to use `psfrag` with pdflatex. Thank you.

Comment: @lockstep: Sorry, I just see that I reverted your capitalization. (You were so keen on that capitalization that you missed the typo in the title `:-)`) As I see it, if we talk about the _program_ pdflatex, we don't use capitalization.

Comment: I will also thank you both, as they were originally my typos.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I recommend (disclaimer,  I wrote them both) either of the `pstool` or the `auto-pst-pdf` packages. The latter is more useful when you have other PSTricks material; `pstool` is better when you only have `psfrag` material only. (One day I'd like to extend `pstool` to handle both cases.)

They both use the `-shell-escape` feature to process the `psfrag` graphics separately before inserting them into the document.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I put auto-pst-pdf in for using pstricks and used the --shell-escape feature. Does this mean that I can just include psfrag as well as pstricks after including the auto-pst-pdf package? p.s. did you not include links because you wrote them?

Comment: @Dom — it's late and I'm too lazy to include links `:)` If you're using a recent MiKTeX or TeX Live you should have the packages installed already. For `psfrag` usage in `auto-pst-pdf`, you must surround the graphics with `\begin{postscript}...\end{postscript}`. See the `pst-pdf` (no `auto-`) documentation for further information.

Comment: Thanks, this worked very well. Only thing I will say is it is very slow with large eps files (approx 2Mb) and Ghostscript maxed out my cpu for around 5 mins! I like it though, makes everything much easier.

Comment: @Dom that sounds about right. Do you need such big eps files though? Sounds like possibly you've got big bitmaps which would be better off in PNG from the start, or very highly sampled plots that could be decimated. What sorts of figures are they?

Comment: It's highly sampled plots, Plot3d generated by mathematica. I don't need it, and I'm thinking about removing the 3d plot in favour of a clearer contour version anyway.

Answer (score 2):

After some further googling I found something potentially useful.
It seems someone has written a bourne-shell script and package that work together, it's called [pdfrack](http://www.onera.fr/staff/marc-boyer/docs/pdfrack/pdfrack%281%29.pdf).

After a quick read of the instructions, it seems you create your document and run the shell script first to generate pdf pictures of the eps files with the psfrag replacements.
Then you run pdflatex normally on your document, to build the pdf including the pdf pictures already generated by the [pdfrack](http://www.onera.fr/staff/marc-boyer/docs/pdfrack/pdfrack%281%29.pdf) package.

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this yet, and to be honest, Will Robertson's answer seems to be the easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote an answer to the similar question [psfrag substitute when using pdflatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145130/psfrag-substitute-when-using-pdflatex).

I am doing Latex marking on .pdf with Inkscape. Basically when saving a picture into pdf, you can select an option "filter all text and write it in an ancillary file". Then Inkscape creates two outputs, the pdf image without any text and a tex file you include, which places text on the pdf image. There is nothing much more to do than open-and-save your pdf, then replace `\includegraphics{mypix.pdf}` by `\include{mypix.pdf-tex}`, the file created by inkscape.

Comment: I don't know how this solves the problem. Could you show some example?

Comment: Some more help and examples [on the online documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/svg-inkscape/)

Note that here you first load your pdf file with "recognise text fields" before the steps described