# How to disable the automatic save of .eps as .pdf?

Tags: pdf, eps, auto-pst-pdf

I tried this [psfrag substitute when using pdflatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145130/psfrag-substitute-when-using-pdflatex?answertab=active#tab-top). The file `myextractor.sty` and the configurations of `main.tex` work very well, but now I have a problem, I want to disable the extraction of `.eps` files as `.pdf`. First I deleted the lines:

```
\usepackage{myextractor}% automatically load graphicx

\graphicspath{{Images/}}
```

but when I compile `main.tex` as `Latex -> PDF` in TexnicCenter it is still generating the `.pdf` files of the `.eps` images. I deleted the `myextractor.sty` file from path, but it is still generating these files, I uninstalled MikTex and TexnicCenter and also I deleted the temporal archives, but when I reinstall and compile `main.tex` it continues generating the `.pdf` of each image. And now every file that I compile as `Latex -> PDF` generates the `.pdf` version of the images (I work only with `.eps`) even if they do not have the lines above or the `myextractor.sty` file in path, included figures out of project/Images.

These only happens when I compile as `Latex -> PDF`, if I compile in any other way it works fine and does not generate the `.pdf` version of the `eps`.

How can I disable these "configuration"?. Some times I have a lot of images and this generates too many archives in DropBox.

Note: Before I tried this method I worked with `.eps` images and `Latex -> PDF` without problem.

This is a simple example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{anysize}

\marginsize{2.50cm}{2.50cm}{1.50cm}{1.50cm}

\title{Test}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\captionsetup{font=footnotesize,labelsep=period}

\maketitle

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{Img1.eps}
\caption{Image.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The `.log` is:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.1.29)  30 JAN 2019 11:04
entering extended mode
**./Article1.tex
(Article1.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size11.clo"
File: size11.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty"
Package: inputenc 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/float\float.sty"
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count88
\float@exts=\toks17
\float@box=\box27
\@float@everytoks=\toks18
\@floatcapt=\box28
)
(C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/caption\caption.sty
Package: caption 2018/10/06 v3.3-154 Customizing captions (AR)

(C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/caption\caption3.sty
Package: caption3 2018/09/12 v1.8c caption3 kernel (AR)
Package caption3 Info: TeX engine: e-TeX on input line 64.
\captionmargin=\dimen105
\captionmargin@=\dimen106
\captionwidth=\dimen107
\caption@tempdima=\dimen108
\caption@indent=\dimen109
\caption@parindent=\dimen110
\caption@hangindent=\dimen111
)
\c@caption@flags=\count89
\c@ContinuedFloat=\count90
Package caption Info: float package is loaded.
)
(C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/anysize\anysize.sty
Package: anysize 1994/08/13 setting margin sizes

document style option `anysize' loaded
Michael Salzenberg, Thomas Esser, Dirk Hillbrecht
Version 1.0, Aug 13, 1994
\@Leftmargin=\dimen112
\@Rightmargin=\dimen113
\@Topmargin=\dimen114
\@Bottommargin=\dimen115
) (Article1.aux)
\openout1 = `Article1.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 16.
 (C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/context/base\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count91
\scratchdimen=\dimen116
\scratchbox=\box29
\nofMPsegments=\count92
\nofMParguments=\count93
\everyMPshowfont=\toks19
\MPscratchCnt=\count94
\MPscratchDim=\dimen117
\MPnumerator=\count95
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count96
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks20
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty"
Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\grfext.sty"
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\kvdefinekeys.sty"
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
))))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
Package: pdftexcmds 2018/09/10 v0.29 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 438.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 456.
)
Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 20.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 20.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 20.
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <Img1.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2018-07-12 14:32:42
(epstopdf)                    size: 30384 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <Img1-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2019-01-30 11:03:30
(epstopdf)                    size: 8399 bytes
(epstopdf)             Command: <epstopdf --outfile=Img1-eps-converted-to.pdf Img1.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 26.
Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate.


pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file ./Img1-eps-converted-to.pdf): PDF inclusion: found PDF version <1.7>, but at most ver
sion <1.5> allowed
<Img1-eps-converted-to.pdf, id=1, 255.95625pt x 150.5625pt>
File: Img1-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use Img1-eps-converted-to.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: Img1-eps-converted-to.pdf  used on input line 26.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 255.95561pt x 150.56212pt.
[1

{C:/Users/Marco/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map} <./Img1-eps-converted-to.pdf>] (Article1.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2626 strings out of 492946
 41868 string characters out of 3135527
 104281 words of memory out of 3000000
 6517 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 7274 words of font info for 26 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 41i,6n,39p,277b,317s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Pr
ogram Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts
/cm/cmr12.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/t
ype1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr9.pfb>
Output written on Article1.pdf (1 page, 48420 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 26 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 6 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you show the first few lines of your .log file?

Comment: it should not re-convert after the first time, but you can always just use `\includegraphics` directly on the pdf (pdflatex can not include eps, so you need to convert the eps to pdf but you only need to do it once)

Comment: You are compiling with pdflatex, this means that you need the pdf versions of your images (and pdflatex will therefore automatically convert the eps to pdf). If you want to use the eps image, compile with latex instead of pdflatex

Comment: Yes I agree, but I guess before, the `.pdf` version of the images were saved as  temporal files and now It saves them in the same folder where it is my project. Sure sometimes it is very useful, but other times my folders are filled with those files. If this is the case I want to return back to the original configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress the loading of epstopdf by defining `\DoNotLoadEpstopdf`:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\newcommand\DoNotLoadEpstopdf{}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{myfigure.eps}
\end{document}
```

This naturally means that pdflatex can't handle the image, and will fall back to draft mode:

[image]