# Why is the output not in landscape as specified in the call of geometry?

Tags: geometry, landscape, dvips, ps2pdf

Why is this code not producing a landscape pdf page when compiled with
LaTeX->dvips->ps2pdf? Checking the resulting ps file shows that it is not in landscape either.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[letterpaper,landscape,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent 0in

\begin{document}

\centerline{\includegraphics[height=\textheight]{example-image-a.eps}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: works fine for me. Is your tex system up-to-date?

Comment: There is a command `dvi2ps` in some distribution. However, `geometry`
does not support the `dvi2ps`. You have to use `dvips` instead of
`dvi2ps`. I think that there is no reason to use `dvi2ps` in these
days.

Comment: Off-topic: The options `left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in` can be stated more succinctly as `margin=1in`.

Comment: @ Akira Kakuto, I actually use dvips. I misstated earlier. @Ulrike Fischer
I forgot that I have an old system with MiKTeX 2.9. It works fine on that laptop. But, on the newest MiKTeX installation, I still get the portrait. I updated the question with more information.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you use `dvips`, `ps2pdf` rather than just compiling with `pdflatex`, or is it just an old habit?  Going via dvi is generally considered outdated today — compiling direct to pdf is much more robust and produces better output.

Comment: @Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine That is a good question! Sometimes I use psfrag and I had great success with this package. Some time ago I looked for a pdflatex alternative to psfrag and was not successful finding one. Is there one? However, I should start using pdf pictures and compiling directly to pdf to get familiarized with the process.

Comment: @wdacda: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11839/using-psfrag-with-pdflatex/11844#11844 :-)

Answer (score 4):

I tested this file on an old MiKTeX 2.9 installation and it works well. It produces a pdf file in the landscape orientation. dvips in this installation is from 2011-07-29, 249 KB.

However, I just installed the newest version of MiKTeX 20.7 and it produces a pdf file in the portrait orientation.

I identified that the problem is with WinEdt. When I call dvips from WinEdt I get a ps file in portrait; when I run dvips from the command prompt I get a ps file in landscape. Looking into the WinEdt settings on the new installation in "Console Applications" settings for dvi2ps in the item "Paper Size and Orientation" one must select "Default". The wrong output was the result of the selection of the "Letter" option in the item "Paper Size and Orientation".