# Including both PDF and EPS files (chemnum + auto-pst-pdf)

Tags: pdf, eps, auto-pst-pdf, chemnum

I'm replacing strings within EPS files using the chemnum package. As I prefer to use pdflatex, auto-pst-pdf should be required as well. So, compiling mwe.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a.eps}
\end{figure}

\nobreakspace

\begin{figure}
\replacecmpd[tag=B]{B}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b.eps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

with `pdflatex --shell-escape mwe.tex` on an up-to-date TeX Live 2019 distribution/Windows 10 x64 will give:

[image]

However, I prefer to [include PDF files wherever possible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2092/which-figure-type-to-use-pdf-or-eps) so that EPS is only used where `\replacecmpd` is really required. If the first of the two `\includegraphics` is replaced by its PDF analogue, the input file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a.pdf}
\end{figure}

\nobreakspace

\begin{figure}
\replacecmpd[tag=B]{B}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b.eps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

will produce a document where only example-image-a was typeset. The EPS file will not be processed. The log file will show the following suspicious lines:

```
<c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-a.pdf>] [2
<c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-b.eps>]
Error: /undefined in obj
Operand stack:
   6   0
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   2022   1   3   %oparray_pop   2021   1   3   %oparray_pop   2009   1   3   %oparray_pop   1865   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:736/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:128/200(L)--   --dict:177/300(L)--   --dict:70/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 324785
GPL Ghostscript 9.50: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
system returned with code 1
PDFCROP 1.38, 2012/11/02 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.

!!! Warning: Empty Bounding Box is returned by Ghostscript!
!!!   Page 1: 0 0 0 0
!!! Either there is a problem with the page or with Ghostscript.
!!! Recovery is tried by embedding the page in its original size.

==> 1 page written on `mwe-pics.pdf'.
"-------------------------------------------------"
"auto-pst-pdf: End auxiliary LaTeX compilation"
"-------------------------------------------------"
```

I appreciate your ideas regarding this issue.

---

simpler example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a.pdf}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I can confirm the PS error, I added a simpler example as chemnum isn't really involved. However if I try that example in texlive 2018 I get a different error (tex not postscript)

Comment: https://github.com/rolfn/pst-pdf/issues/1

Comment: Thanks David! So I will wait for package updates.

Comment: I can now confirm that the problem is gone after updating my TeX Live 2019 distribution.

Comment: thanks for confirming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it describes has been fixed in an up to date distribution.